# What happens if I disable the loopback device using ifconfig?

Tags: networking, ifconfig

I found out that I can disable my interfaces using

```
$ sudo ifconfig lo down
```

I want to know what happens if I disable my loopback interface forever. It's disabled now and nothing has changed. Are there any disadvantages that I can't see now?

Comment: Next time, search before asking: https://superuser.com/questions/521916/linux-disable-loopback-interface-from-kernel

Comment: @mikewhatever would you please explain about your link? That link is about if we can disable `loopback interface` from the kernel. I want to know what is the disadvantages of disabling `loobpack` using `ifconfig` command.

Comment: You may want to run `sudo lsof -i` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used by various local services which will fail when `lo` is down. Many local service make use of a Unix socket and of course those will continue to work. Those using a TCP socket, however...

Here is a picture of my firewall and we can see that there are quite a few packets going through....

[image]